# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement qscintilla==2.11.4

Tags: linux-mint, python, pip

I was trying to install python packages for Mu Editor on Linux Mint when I ran into the following error:

```
$ pip3 install qscintilla==2.11.4
  Collecting qscintilla==2.11.4
   Could not find a version that satisfies the 
   requirement qscintilla==2.11.4 (from versions: 
   2.9.4, 2.10, 2.10.1, 2.10.2, 2.10.3, 2.10.4, 
   2.10.7, 2.10.8, 2.11, 2.11.1, 2.11.2, 2.11.3)
 No matching distribution found for qscintilla==2.11.4
```

Any ideas what's wrong?

UPDATE:

I reinstalled the entirety of mu-editor to be met with this error while trying to install;

```
Collecting mu-editor
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fa/2f/6f7eb7e836a528d6959e5c79491d90faef2df7a78e9d953b84451551a98e/mu_editor-1.0.3-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting guizero>=1.1.0 (from mu-editor)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b0/eb/c58693afb94bc1e5f5f77d0f8e6b4e6dc84006fbfcb66b10fb81aef39f69/guizero-1.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting PyQtChart==5.14.0 (from mu-editor)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c8/6e/08e68bb5c3c64fbb56f1755c0b4748bb82775fa1b7c9fbaa61572eeaa76a/PyQtChart-5.14.0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tokenize.py", line 452, in open
        buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip-build-5lqnol01/PyQtChart/setup.py'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-5lqnol01/PyQtChart/
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Can you add some information on what kind of repositories you have configured?

Comment: Cheers! Reinstalled the program a bit ago with information edited above, sorry for that inconvenience.  Programs installed by Pip usually just go straight to my file system as a folder.